# PCI Compliance + Magento + PHP version

Tags: php, yum, pci-dss, rhel

I'm trying to get PCI Compliance for my dedicated server (Red Hat Enterprise Linux), which is running Magento. When I first installed Magento on the server, I realized that RHEL comes with a PHP version which is too old for Magento (5.1.6). So, I found a separate repo with PHP version 5.2.11, which got everything running fine, but now I'm in a bind. My PCI Compliance test says that since my PHP version is < 5.3.1 it has security issues. If I try to update to 5.3.1, Magento breaks. I don't want to edit the Magento core to fix those problems, so I guess what I need is a repo with PHP 5.2.11, but that I can confidently say/prove has back-ported to patch up the issues that the PCI Compliance scan identifies.

I realize this is terribly convoluted, but if you have any suggestions/tips I'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 5.2.11, that is the current stable version of the 5.2 branch so you would be safe from a PCI perspective (it should be the same as saying I'm running Office 2003 with all the service packs). There won't be any backporting issues as 5.3 and 5.2 are two different sets of code. Bugs in 5.3 will not necessarily affect 5.2 and vice versa.

This is unlike kernels, where Redhat will regularly backport patches. Redhat keeps all the CVE's updated with this information.

Comment: I appealed the scan findings, using something similar to your argument here. It's now passing, so they must have accepted this argument. Thanks!